# Верна ли пунктуация в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

*Строительным фирмам, выполняющим работы в сельской местности трудно обойтись без почасового метода организации работ.*

Comment: Объясните своё решение по имеющимся знакам, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует поставить еще одну запятую, закрывающую причастный оборот.

*Строительным фирмам, **выполняющим работы в сельской местности,** трудно обойтись без почасового метода организации работ.*

> 1. Обособляются (отделяются запятой, а **в середине предложения выделяются с двух сторон запятыми**) распространенные определения, выраженные причастием или прилагательным с зависящими от него словами (так называемые определительные обороты), стоящие после существительного или субстантивированного слова: *По пыльной дороге, **ведущей к садам,** тянулись скрипучие арбы, наполненные чёрным виноградом* (Л. Т.)...

[Справочник Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=274).

Comment: @Максим Не забывайте, пожалуйста, не только принимать ответы галочкой, но и отмечать все полезные ответы (а также вопросы) стрелочкой вверх.